# Binary comparison of strings with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, collation

Is there a way to perform an accent-sensitive, case-sensitive, "padding-sensitive" (pay attention to trailing spaces) query in SQL Server *without* having to tweak both operands?

The following script is from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kekm40jj):

```sql
create table users (
  id   int,
  name varchar(255)
);
```

```sql
insert into users (id, name) 
  values 
  (1, 'bar'),
  (2, 'bar ');
```

Here I expect to find just record #2, it finds both: padding insensitive.

```sql
select * from users where name = 'bar ';
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bar |
| 2 | bar |

It is also case insensitive.

```sql
select * from users where name = 'BAR';
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bar |
| 2 | bar |

But accent sensitive.

```sql
select * from users where name = 'bàz';
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |

Using `_BIN2` seems to make no difference, in spite of (my understanding of) what the documentation says (and it feels unnerving to specify "Latin 1": I do not want to restrict my to the sole ISO-8859-1 fragment, I want the full UTF-8 coverage).  It should find nothing!

```sql
select * from users
where (name collate Latin1_General_BIN2) in ('bàr', 'BAR', 'bar  ');
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bar |
| 2 | bar |

Even when applied on both operands.

```sql
select * from users
where (name collate Latin1_General_CS_AS) in 
  ('bàr' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS, 
  'BAR'  collate Latin1_General_CS_AS, 
  'bar  ' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS);
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bar |
| 2 | bar |

Cast to binary on the left-hand-side only does not work.

```sql
select * from users where cast(name as binary) = 'bar';
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |

Casting on both ends works, but I want to avoid that (it scales poorly when trying more complex queries, possibly with tuples, etc.)

```sql
select * from users where cast(name as binary) = cast('bar' as binary);
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bar |

Casting of both sides works with `in` too.  But then again, I want to avoid that.

```sql
select * from users
where cast(name as binary) in 
  (cast('bàr'  as binary), 
  cast('BAR'   as binary), 
  cast('bar  ' as binary));
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |

So, is there any way to get an exact binary equality test by acting on the left-hand-side only?  Something similar to `binary name = 'bar'` in MySQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you've discovered, the approach involving casting both operands to a binary data type seems to be the most reliable method for exact binary comparisons. However, you're looking for a solution that affects only the left-hand side of the comparison.

Comment: there isn't a built-in, direct way in SQL Server to enforce strict, binary-level comparisons on the LHS alone without affecting the right-hand side as well. I think it is a limitation from SQL Server, since it is focusing on data types and collation rather than MySQL BINARY operator  which directly influences comparison behavior.

Comment: *"Cast to binary on the lhs only does not work."* This is because of [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). When you compare 2 values of differing types (`binary` and `varchar` here) the value with the lowest precedence is converted to the one with the highest. As `binary` has a lower precedent to a `varchar`, then as a result `cast(name as binary) = 'bar'` would end up being executed as `implicit_convert(varchar(3),cast(name as binary)) = 'bar'`.

Comment: `(it scales poorly when trying more complex queries, possibly with tuples, etc.)` pretty sure your indexes won't be used anyway, so not sure how scaling comes into question here, but perhaps you mean that code gets more unmanaged. Them the breaks.

Comment: If performance *is* the real concern, could you use a computed column and then index it? Or create an indexed view?

Comment: There's no `padding-sensitive (pay attention to trailing spaces)`, that's not how SQL, the language works. The SQL standard treats `'bar'` and `'bar '` as the same string. Even MySQL will treat them as equal. `binary name = 'bar'` doesn't change the collation, it casts to varbinary and makes it impossible for the server to use indexes.

Comment: *Why* do you want to include trailing spaces in the comparison? That's where the problem starts. There's probably a better way to solve the actual problem. The current approach contradicts even ANSI SQL 92 and your own question proves that MySQL doesn't allow this without casting. That's a very strong indication that the approach is wrong. There *is* a way to change padding rules but that breaks quite a lot of features. That way only exists for compatibility with pre-2000 code

Comment: @ThomA Thanks a lot for explaining why single-sided casts are useless!

Comment: *"Thanks a lot for explaining why single-sided casts are useless!"* I didn't say that. `WHERE SomeDateTimeValue > CONVERT(date, GETDATE())` wouldn't be a useless single-sided cast.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "Why do you want to include trailing spaces in the comparison?".  Well, because it matters to data I work on.  I came onto this issue not for fun, but by need.  I have strings that play the role of keys, and yes, it matters to match exactly the strings as they are, as plain old hash tables would.  Besides, I'm looking for something portable.  In PG and Oracle it works out of the box.  In MariaDB, I just need to cast to binary on the LHS.  On SQL Server, I'm stuck.

Comment: @siggemannen Sorry for my poor wording: by "scaling" I was referring to "applicable to more complex predicates".  While I'm not looking actively for pessimization, this is not performance critical either.

Comment: @akim that's not an answer - that's a `because I want to`. Your own question shows that you had to cast in MySQL as well: `binary name = 'bar'` is a custom feature equivalent to `cast(name as binary)`. This doesn't work in *any* database without using non-standard functionality. It's the ANSI 92 standard that says padding is ignored, not SQL Sever. Which means that `for something portable` doesn't exist, unless you use `cast( ... as binary). `plain old hash tables would.` there's no such thing in relational systems. That's an implementation term that *shouldn't* affect how queries work

Comment: @akim  `In MariaDB, I just need to cast to binary on the LHS. On SQL Server, I'm stuck.` no, you can use `cast( ...)` as ThomA shows.

Comment: @akim `In PG ... it works out of the box.` not really. Collations are a sore subject in PostgreSQL, as it uses C comparisons by default (it's more complex). `Oracle` no, [as the Oracle docs show](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm). Oracle uses padded comparison for `CHAR`, non-padded for `VARCHAR`

Comment: @ThomA "'Thanks a lot for explaining why single-sided casts are useless!' I didn't say that."  I meant "here", "in the context of the item where I tried it on the left-hand-side only", not in general.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "that's not an answer - `that's a because I want to.`"  No, I personally don't want anything here, I'm just trying to address the business rules I have to implement.  So yes, it's my answer: "that's because I need to".  I could use some terminator, say `$`, but that feels ugly.

Comment: @akim that's how SQL works though, so there's *NO* cross-platform solution except perhaps casting or appending. And even then, the syntax can be different from product to product. The databases you mentioned works the way you assumed. Google for `sql E021-12`, which is the relevant standard section. Some say so explicitly, eg Oracle uses padding for CHAR, no padding for VARCHAR. Others like PostgreSQL claim compliance while violating it. The [Modern SQL site](https://modern-sql.com/standard/levels) explains that databases only need to conform at an entry level. In reality, they still diverge

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I should have emphasized that I'm on varchar, you're right.  And really, again my words were badly chosen: I'm ready to make one translator per target, that's not a problem.  So I have solutions for most of them (some via a cast, others via collation), except for SQL Server where the traversal must be performed on left- and right- operands.  While I fully understand that on char padding is mandatory, I'm pretty surprised that varchar in SQL Server has such a strong char taste.  Thanks for your answer, I'll dive into "Modern SQL".

Answer (score 3):

It seems that what might be best here is to add a computed column to your table that converts the value to a `(var)binary`. As `name` is a `varchar(255)` I'm going to use a `varbinary(255)` here. Then you can `INDEX` that column so that you can query is appropriately. You will, however, still need to `CONVERT` your input values. You therefore might be better off using parameters, as then you can be explicit on the data type and therefore don't end up with someone passing a `varchar` and causes an `implicit_convert`. This gives some DDL and DML like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.users (id int CONSTRAINT PK_users PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                        name varchar(255));

INSERT INTO dbo.users (id,
                   name)
VALUES (1, 'bar'),
       (2, 'bar ');
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.users ADD BinaryName AS CONVERT(varbinary(255),name);
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_users_BinaryName ON dbo.users (BinaryName) INCLUDE (name);
GO
```

Then a query for a single value might look like this:

```sql
DECLARE @name varbinary(255) = CONVERT(varbinary(255),'bàr'); --Implicit conversion isn't allowed

SELECT u.id,
       u.name
FROM dbo.users u
WHERE BinaryName = @name;
```

If you need to multiple values, you might be better off with a table type variable/parameter and something  like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Names table (name varbinary(255));

INSERT INTO @Names (name)
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(255),v.name)
FROM (VALUES('bàr'),('BAR'),('bar  '))V(name);

SELECT u.id,
       u.name
FROM dbo.users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @Names n
              WHERE n.name = u.BinaryName);
```

Comment: +1 - the OP doesn't seem to understand what `binary field` is a cast, not a collation. Even MySQL considers `'bar'` and `'bar '` to be equal. The only way to get acceptable performance in either database is an indexed binary column

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't think of a different way to get the comparison to work as the OP needed with the trailing spaces *without* using a `(var)binary` value, @PanagiotisKanavos . I'm sure *someone* has some voodoo magic out there, but if it's performant might be a different matter.

Comment: Maybe [ANSI_PADDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) OFF ? I never used that and I only remembered it because all SSMS scripts I've seen for decades have `ANSI_PADDING ON`. Some features break if that's OFF (indexed computed columns) and others are probably not tested with it. The docs say `ANSI_PADDING should always be set to ON.` All drivers enable it by default

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not play with turning off ANSI features, @PanagiotisKanavos . They're on for a reason. :)

Comment: @ThomA I really appreciate the time you took to propose a complete solution, thanks a lot!  But it's hardly adaptable to my case.  Basically I'm generating the queries from some AST.  I'm looking for something "local", which I can plug into a bigger tree.  Your solution is "non local" on this regard (it's not just a rewriting rule).
Having to traverse the whole RHS and apply the cast everywhere is not as local as "just the LHS", but it is local nonetheless.  However, my main concern here is that it because very invasive if the RHS is complex (e.g., I'm using an IN on tuples).
Thanks again!

Comment: I have no idea what an AST, LHS, or RHS is, @akim (unless you mean Royal Horticultural Society, but I assume not). I have no idea what you mean by it being a "local" solution either, I'm afraid. It seems like you've not told us a lot of information about the problem or what you've asked if an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info). Perhaps you need to be telling us the *full* picture, or explaining what *X* is. Though, if you are doing that, it likely needs to be in a new question, as you're likely to invalidate this answer otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like he's parsing and transforming some sql queries and wants to apply the binary comparing automatically for whatever reasons, but too lazy to fix the "right" side (RHS) of the code transformation that needs to be done to force the binary compare.  Don't think there are any easy shortcuts to fix that unfortunately

Comment: "too lazy to fix the 'right' side (RHS)".  Thanks for the kind words :)  In practice, yes, I face a bazillion of node types, open ended.  While the database knows perfectly well the query it is working on.

Comment: @ThomA Sorry for the jargon. AST is abstract-syntax tree (basically what a parser extracts from a source file), LHS is left-hand side, and RHS is 'left' as an exercise to the reader.  And the whole picture is: I have an AST denoting some SQL query in which an operator denotes equality in its non-SQL usual meaning.  With most DBs it suffices to "tag" the value you are interested in via a cast or collation (depending on the DB), while SQL Server seems to require a traversal of all operands.  Yes, just a cast/collation is simpler, but also more powerful, since you can assemble richer queries.